# How can I stress test my Facebook Messenger App

Tags: messenger

I created a Facebook Messenger bot app, I want to know if my messenger bot app will work well when 1000 people or more are using it. Is there some way to stress test it? For example, if 1000 people are using it, I want to see if the app will crash or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use siege to stress test your messenger webhooks. Spin up 1000 concurrent users to see if your servers can handle the request.

https://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/